# Monitor a process in Debian

Tags: shell, debian, monitoring, services

I want to create a service that monitors the existence of a certain process. I wrote the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
w=`ps u -A | grep -P ".+Sl.+/usr/local/MySource/endpoint" -c`
sleep 10
if [ $w -lt 2 ] 
then
echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/alix\:2/brightness
killall -9 /usr/local/MySource/endpoint
nohup /usr/local/MySource/endpoint &> /dev/null &
last_endpoint_m=`date`
echo $last_endpoint_m > /tmp/endpoint_msleep
echo $w >> /tmp/endpoint_msleep
else
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/alix\:2/brightness
fi
sleep 10
done
```

If the process exists, the script will switch off a LED on my machine and start the process. The LED should be `ON` while the process is running.

I then run this script by adding the following line to `/etc/rc.local`:

```
nohup /usr/local/MyTools/additions/XR50_endpoint_m &> /dev/null &
```

When I run `ps`, I find that the `XR50_endpoint_m &` process is there.

My Machine is an ALIX board with limited resources (embedded) running Debian.

The question is:
The variable `$w` is always zero (I verified this from the output file `/tmp/endpoint_msleep`). Although the process exists and the script is working fine if I run it manually (`$w=2`)!

What do you think the reason is and what is the best way to monitor a process?

Comment: Did the answer work ?

Comment: Log the output of `ps u -A` to a file to see exactly what's there. Are you sure the state is `Al`? You should use the `-o` option to `ps` instead of doing this dodgy filtering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>It is failing because you run `ps u`. From `man ps`:</del>

<del>u      Display user-oriented format.</del>

<del>This means that `ps` will only list processes owned by the current user. When you run the script manually, that user is you so your process is listed correctly.</del>

(As @Gilles very correctly pointed out, the use of `-A` will cause all processes to be printed so that explanation is just wrong. `pgrep` is still better though).

---

Anyway, a better way of doing this would be to use `pgrep`:

```
   pgrep,  pkill  - look up or signal processes based on
   name and other attributes
```

Change

```
w=`ps u -A | grep -P ".+Sl.+/usr/local/MySource/endpoint" -c`
```

to

```
w=`pgrep -c endpoint`
```

Comment: `u` sets the display format, it doesn't affect the selection of processes. With `-A`, all processes are displayed.

Comment: `"` should be replaced by `. Thank you.

Comment: @user45980 so it should, thanks for pointing it out. However, (as usual) @Gilles is quite right and `u` with `-A` should print processes for all users. You should still use `pgrep` since that is what it is designed for but my original explanation for why it fails is wrong.